# 404 Not Found @angular/platform-browser.js

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5, systemjs, jspm

I try setup `ASP.NET MVC 5` (not Core) + Angular 2.0.0 + JSPM + SystemJS + [TS Loader](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript).

When I run app I get error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:59711/@angular/platform-browser.js

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:59711/@angular/platform-browser.js(…)
```

@angular packages are in folder jspm_packeges/npm.

Now I really don’t know what is root of problem some breaking change in Angular or something in SystemJS.

Here are my configuration files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    /* target of the compilation (es5) */
    "module": "system",
    /* System.register([dependencies], function) (in JS)*/
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* how module gets resolved (needed for Angular 2)*/
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    /* needed for decorators */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    /* needed for decorators (@Injectable) */
    "noImplicitAny": false
    /* any has to be written explicity*/
  },
  "exclude": [
    /* since compiling these packages could take ages, we want to ignore them*/
    "jspm_packages",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
  /* on default the compiler will create js files */
}
```

**config.js (jspm, configuration files is simplified)**

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  typescriptOptions: {
    "tsconfig": true
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "main": "bootstrap",
      "format": "system",
      "defaultExtensions": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  map: {
    "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common@2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core@2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "npm:@angular/http@2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "npm:@angular/router@3.0.0",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.38",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@5.1.2",
    "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.6.23",
    "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@5.1.2": {
      "typescript": "npm:typescript@2.0.2"

      //...
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
    System.config
    ({
        transpiler: "ts",
        packages:
        {
            "app": {
                "defaultExtension": "ts",
            }
        }
    });

System.import('app/bootstrap').catch(console.log.bind(console));
</script>
```

Visual Studio complains for all angular imports.

**bootstrap.js**

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser"
import {provide} from "@angular/core"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like: **'@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0** package is missing.

```
map: {
    "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common@2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0",
     ...
     ...
    '@angular/platform-browser': "npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0"
     ...
     ...
}
```

Note: Also add it to **package.json** if already not there,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
     ...
     ...
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
     ...
}
```

Comment: I tried add map to System.config in _Layout.cshtml but it give me Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'angular' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Package.json config is OK. Do you mean add map section to jspm or systemjs configuration file ? Because in jspm I had already.

Comment: I mean `systemjs.config.js` file. There in `map object` you have to do mentioned change.

Comment: In ASP.NET Razor directive start with @ maybe this is problem

Comment: Yes, it was Razor view I needed only escape @ with double @ but error ist still same.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with VS.

Comment: Thank you, problem is  fixed now